# Regex not working in curl output

Tags: regex, shell, curl, grep

Im using curl to send a POST request in debian linux terminal and its working properly, This is the curl command:

```
curl --data "ping=8.8.8.8" -s http://www.ipvoid.com/ping/
```

Now i want to capture the content between the `<textarea>` tags by executing this command:

```
curl --data "ping=8.8.8.8" -s http://www.ipvoid.com/ping/ | grep -ioE '<textarea.*>(.*(\n.*)*)<\/textarea>'
```

But it returns nothing. I tested the regex and it works properly:

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/J15a6x/1)

Is the problem with the regex or grep syntax?

Comment: It works when your input is a multiline string. `grep` parses input line by line.

Comment: The xmllint answer is obviously the best, but the perl is:  `perl -0 -ne 'print for /<textarea.*>([\s\S]*?)<\/textarea>/gi'`  (Your regex works too, if you make the inner group non-capturing (`(?:)`)

Comment: using `grep -Pzo "<textarea.*>(.*(\n.*)*)<\/textarea>"` but <textarea> tag still exist

Comment: @zzxyz worked perfect with `perl`

Answer (score 2):

Since the result of the crucial HTTP request is HTML document the right way is to apply xml/html parsers.

**`xmllint`** is one of such:

```
curl -d "ping=8.8.8.8" -s http://www.ipvoid.com/ping/ \
| xmllint --html --xpath '//textarea/text()' - 2>/dev/null
```

The output:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=1.12 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=61 time=1.05 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=61 time=1.14 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.052/1.107/1.144/0.039 ms
```

http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html

Answer (score 0):

by default, grep parses the input individually per line, and your textarea has newlines in it, thus your regex doesn't work. but you can (ab)use the `--null-data` parameter, then it will separate the input by NULL bytes instead of newlines, and since there's no NULL bytes in your textarea, it works!

```
curl --data "ping=8.8.8.8" -s http://www.ipvoid.com/ping/ | grep -ioE '<textarea.*>(.*(\n.*)*)<\/textarea>' --null-data
```

(but i recommend using a proper HTML parser instead, the xmllint recommended by @RomanPerekhrest would probably be a better solution, if it's available to you)

Comment: This will return the `<textarea>` too. I just want the content between the tags. That xmllint seems working but i want to do this with grep or perl which is possible, Already done with perl in @zzxyz comment, Now im trying with grep.